# Adjust padding width of specific div class with Stylish?

Tags: css, stylish

I'm trying to adjust the padding at the top of Twitter pages I visit to make up for having blocked an annoying element with an ad blocker. I've identified the html that needs to be adjusted as
div class="topbar-spacer" style="**padding-top: 108px**;"

My attempted fix was:

> ```
> @-moz-document domain("twitter.com") {
> .topbar-spacer {
>     padding-top: 50px
> }
> ```

but this doesn't seem to be working and I'm unsure why.

Comment: Inline styles have a higher specificity score than classes. Try adding `!important`.

Comment: That seems to have worked. Thank you!